# Two GET functions in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, server

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    //code and return
}

public Employee GetSingleEmployee(int Id)
{
    //code and return 
}
```

This is what I have now. I'm trying to make the app call the first function with a get call api/employee and the second one with a get call api/employee/(an ID number) eg api/employee/75. The get call always goes to the first one. How do I solve this?

This is my routing:

```
 namespace EmployeeApp
 {
    public class RouteConfig
    {
          public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
          {
                    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
           }
     }
 }
```

Comment: show your routing. By default `id` instead of `Id` should work

Comment: We need to see your routing in order to help.. it might be a querystring issue.

Comment: That routing looks like the default for the MVC routing - not web api

Comment: Oh. I am really new into this. I might have set up my project wrong. How would I do this in MVC then?

Answer (score 4):

Use annotation like

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("employee")]
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    //code and return
}
[HttpGet]
[Route("employee/{Id}")]
public Employee GetSingleEmployee(int Id)
{
    //code and return 
}
```

On class above you RoutePrefix to

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated without seeing your routing it could be difficult to guess but assuming it is something like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

the optional `id` parameter should work as long as the method parameter is lowercase.

If you want to use the action as part of the routing then use this, placing it above the default route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Api By Action",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```